# Need help in python regex

Tags: python

I have list of file in directory:

```
gp_dump_0_10_20171112003450 <==
gp_dump_0_11_20171112003450 <==
gp_dump_0_12_20171112003450 <==
gp_dump_0_13_20171112003450 <==
gp_dump_0_14_20171112003450 <==
gp_dump_1_1_20171112003450 <==
gp_dump_1_1_20171112003450_post_data
gp_dump_20171112003450_ao_state_file
gp_dump_20171112003450_co_state_file
gp_dump_20171112003450_last_operation
gp_dump_20171112003450.rpt
```

I want to fetch only marked ( <==) files from a directory. Below is the python code I have written which is not working as expected:

```
import os
import re

dump_key = 20171112003450
backup_files = os.listdir('/home/jadhavy/backup/')
segment_file_regex = "gp_dump_\d+?_\d+?_%s$" %dump_key
for file in backup_files:
        if file == re.finditer(segment_file_regex,file,re.S):
                print(file)
```

EDIT:Changed regex to match end, I'm not getting any result after running this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two main things:

1. To check if a string matches a pattern, the function you want is `re.match`, not `re.finditer`.  `re.match` will return a match object if the pattern matches the string at the beginning, or `None` if there is no match.
2. The regex will also match `gp_dump_1_1_20171112003450_post_data` because it starts with a match.  The `$` metacharacter in a regex means the end-of-string, so if you put it at the end of the pattern it won't match strings with trailing characters.

Here is your code with the above adjustments:

```
import os
import re

dump_key = 20171112003450
backup_files = os.listdir('/home/jadhavy/backup/')
segment_file_regex = "gp_dump_\d+?_\d+?_%s$" %dump_key
for file in backup_files:
        if re.match(segment_file_regex,file,re.S):
                print(file)
```

Three other tips:

1. You shouldn't need the `re.S` flag in this case, because it only affects the `.` metacharacter.
2. Raw strings are usually a good idea when writing regexes to avoid accidentally interpreting one character as another since regexes tend to contain lots of backslashes.  For example, `r'\n'` becomes `'\\n'` instead of `'\n'` (newline).
3. When inserting a string into a regex, you can use `re.escape` to escape metacharacters.  For example `r'abc%sghi' % re.escape('[def]')` becomes `r'abc\[def\]ghi'` instead of `r'abc[def]ghi'` which isn't the regex you'd want.

Comment: You don't need `\d+?_`, because the underscores will stop the match anyway.

Comment: That reminds me, you can also use `\d*` instead of `\d+?` if the intent is to match 0 or more digits.